# Javascript use variable as property name to toggle Booleans

Tags: javascript

How can I solve the problem in the code below?

The problem is I want to toggle the Booleans in my GUI.
I can save the "An" and "sta" in variables.

```
var a={
  "An":{
    "sta":true,
    "stb":false
  },
  "Bn":{
    "sta":false,
    "stb":false
  },
};

var x="sta";
console.log(a.An.sta);//true
console.log(a.An.x);//undefined
```

If I want to change the Boolean of "sta" in "An" from true to false then I can do it with a line like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(arr.An, "sta", {value: false});
```

or:

```
arr.An.sta=false;
```

Then I can toggle the Boolean with:

```
if(a.An.x==true){
a.An.sta=false;
}
```

The message that I get from the example code in codepen is "undefined", if I do it with a variable x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solved my problem. It was just a spelling mistake. `a.An.y-->a.An[y]`

```
var a={
  "An":{
    "sta":true,
    "stb":false
  },
  "Bn":{
    "sta":false,
    "stb":false,
    "test": "stb"
  },
};
var y=a.Bn.test;
console.log(a.An.sta);//true
console.log(a.An[y]);//false
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you?

```
var a={
  "An":{
    "sta":true,
    "stb":false
  },
  "Bn":{
    "sta":false,
    "stb":false
  },
};

var x=function(arg) {return arg;}
a.An.x=x("sta");
console.log(a.An.sta);//true
console.log(a.An.x);//sta
```